# Python: Reading marks from a file then using marks to get class

Tags: python, file, text-files, readfile, notepad

I have gotten this sheet and I am having trouble with it. [The Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDrjZ.png)

This is my notepad txt: [maths_mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpprG.png)
I want to create it like if:

- mark => 90 = 10M1
- mark => 80 = 10M2
- mark => 70 = 10M3
- mark => 60 = 10M4
- mark => 50 = 10M5
- mark => 40 = 10M6
- mark => 30 = 10M7
- mark => 20 = 10M8
- mark => 10 = 10M9

I am stuck on how to read the marks from the file then creating a new text file with the names, marks and class.

If anyone can be any help, it would be appreciated.

Thanks, Noob Coder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

# function to process data
def process_data(data):
    for item in data:
        marks = int(item[2])
        mclass = 'incorrect data entry try again'
        if marks == 0:
            mclass = "10.9"
        elif marks >= 0 and marks <= 100:
            mclass = "10.{}".format(10 - int(item[2][0]))
        yield '"{}","{}",{},{}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[2],mclass)

# read data to memory
data = []
with open("Maths_Mark.txt", "r") as csv_in:
    data = list(csv.reader(csv_in, delimiter=','))

# write contents to file
with open('Maths_Group.txt', 'w') as csv_out:
    for line in process_data(data):
        csv_out.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Hey when I run your code, when a score of 100 is existing, it doesnt out the class into 10m9 instead of 10m1

Comment: Thought 100 falls into the case of 90-100. Move it along with the 0 condition check will fix that. So if marks == 0 or marks == 100 and elif marks > 0 and marks < 100

Comment: I found another problem. When the mark is single digit it is wrong for eg. mark = 6, maths_class = 10M4.

Comment: I think its better to do individual conditional checks than using my trick. Was being lazy there. Because as soon as we add more conditions the purpose of my indexing trick is useless.  So replace my conditions and do range checks like if mark > 0 and mark <= 10: mclass = “ likewise.

Answer (score 0):

[A bit of google can help here](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html) that article has all you need as far as opening and writing to files. To set you on the right path:
You can just call `f=open("fileName.txt","w+")` which will open up your existing file for you and store it into a variable. Then you can `file_line=f.readlines()` to grab one line at a time. Manipulate the result as you need. Recreate a new string variable with the result of your manipulation `result= "My data"` and then use `f2=open("newFileName.txt","w+")` with a new file name to create a new file on which you will use `f2.write(result)` in order to write to the file. Make sure to close our your files `f.close(),f2.close()`

The data manipulation portion is up to you!

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck on how to read the marks from the file then creating a new
>   text file with the names, marks and class.

```
fileList = list()
with open("Maths_Marks", 'r') as fp:
        fp = fp.readlines()
        for line in fp:
            tmpLine = line.split(",")
            sname = tmpLine[0]
            fname = tmpLine [1]
            marks = tmpLine[2]
            #Write your own logic to get GroupNumber.
            #Append into line using
            #line = line.strip() + "," + GroupNumber
            #fileList.append(line.strip())


#Open new file Maths_Group and write into that
with open("Maths_Group",'w') as s:
     for line  in filelist:
         print >> s, line
```

> "line" will give you "Jack,Daniels,90"
>
> line = line.strip() + "," + GroupNumber  => will give you  Jack,Daniels,90,10M1

If you want to extract each field then use else leave below part.

```
sname = tmpLine[0]
fname = tmpLine[1]
marks = tmpLine[2]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added `if marks >= 90:`
`GroupNumber = "10M1"`
When I run it, it comes up with an error, TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Please use if int(marks) >=90:
                GroupNumber = "10M1"  . This will work. Let me know it's working or not for you.

Comment: sname = tmpLine [1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: is there an alternative way to make the code more efficient and clean instead of using "if" statements?

Comment: can you plz provide code link? I will check. Bcoz if your i/p file is the same the way your sample file was, then you should not face this error.

Comment: Sorry for the whole line. How do I paste code in properly?

Comment: https://github.com/nagbansi/Intro-To-Machine-Learning/blob/master/examples/Reading%20Marks  Check the complete code and it is working with your sample "Maths_Marks".  Code is written in pythonic way. Let me know if still you are facing issue.

Comment: pythonic code? Is this somewhat pseudo code? When I run since there are parentheses, it gives an error

Comment: I ran this code with your sample "Maths_Marks" and works fine. Where is parenthesis?

Comment: File ".\readmarkwriteclass.py", line 5
    print line
             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(line)?

Comment: Is this Python 2?

Comment: yes I am using python 2.7. You can change the print syntax in python 3. http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function follow this and change accordingly. I hope this will help.